# Visual C++ 6.0 - Why array bounds overflow?

Tags: arrays, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ and I have to use array. The problem is I get error "array bounds overflow" in this line:

```
char arr[2] = "12";
```

But when I changed it to:

```
char arr[3] = "12";
```

it works fine but why?

**Update:**

And this works :(

```
char arr[2] = {'1','2'};
```

I'm really confused about the difference between declarations, how they are stored in the memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the C family of languages the memory spaces which represent strings ( `char arrays` ) are terminated by the null character `\0`

Thus the memory to store the string must be at least one character larger than the expected size when you write it out with `" "`

Your new example, isn't creating a string, but rather an array of characters. Because you have switched notations form `" "` to `{ }` the system is no longer creating a null terminated string but is rather creating an array as that is what you have asked for.

The crux of it is that Strings are special and have `\0` tacked onto their end by the system automatically and therefore need additional space.

Comment: Huh? But when I use Borland C++ 4.5 `char arr[2] = "12";
` works fine. Why do you think? And if I add one to the length, how should I access the array? Should I start from 0?

Comment: Quirk of the compiler in the case of Borland - Strings are arrays and are indexed from 0

Comment: I'm still confused, string is not array of characters?

Comment: All strings are arrays of characters but not all arrays of characters are strings.

Answer (score 3):

The char array has a null terminating character "\0" at the end of every string.  You always need to reserve an additional space in your array for this character.

Answer (score 3):

That's because literal strings in C and C++ have an implied '\0' appended to them. It's called a zero-terminated string, it helps when trying to keep track of the length of the string, instead of storing it explicitly somewhere in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Because string constants must store a NUL at the end of string, 2 chars of storage is not enough, hence the overflow. You need to store '1', '2', and NUL which is 3 chars.